# When do I say "food" or "foods"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns, uncountable-nouns

As I have read that the noun "food" is generally uncountable, I am not quite sure when I should use "food" as a countable noun.

For instance,

> Chicken and rice are **food**

or

> Chicken and rice are **foods**

Could I use a number in front of *foods*?

> Chicken and rice are **two foods**?

Should we use *food* or *foods* here?

Comment: "Food" is always a mass noun except when it means "kinds of food". So: "High carb foods", "Gluten-free foods." "Chicken and rice are food", but ""Chicken and rice are nutritious foods".

Comment: @P.E.Dant you should make your comment into an answer. It's +1 from me, if you do.

Comment: @P.E.Dant your comment has five upvotes. Please, just copy your comment in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

## It depends on what you mean.

> **Chicken and rice are food**.

Chicken and rice are members of the category 'food'. They are stuff you can eat.

> **Chickens and rice are food**.

This is the same thing, but referring to the natural state of chickens as individual animals and (by analogy) to rice as a plant. These things, which you can find in nature, can be eaten.

> **Chicken and rice are foods**.

Both chicken and rice are *kinds* of food. Either one, taken separately, is a *kind* of stuff you can eat.

> **Chicken and rice are two foods**.

This is the same thing, emphasizing that these are just two options out of a larger category.

> **Chickens and rice are foods**.
>   **Chicken and rice are two food**.

These are just wrong. 'Chickens' are not a foodstuff but the animals themselves; they are not a *kind* of food but a *source* of it. Uncountable nouns are definitionally not able to be counted.

When to use them depends on the categories you're talking about.

Chickens are (for most people) *food* but (for everyone) they are an animal and not a subcategory of foodstuff (i.e., *a food*); chicken and rice are both *food* and kinds of food (i.e., *foods*); chicken and rice can be Vietnamese *food* but are not kinds of Vietnamese food (i.e., *foods*); *com chien* and *banh tet* are kinds of Vietnamese food (i.e., *foods*).

Answer (score 1):

"Food" is always a mass noun, except when used to mean "kinds of food." For example:

- *Baby foods* – the varieties of food eaten by babies.
- *Gluten-free foods* – varieties of food that do not contain gluten.
- *Processed foods* – ready-to-eat or pre-prepared food, often less healthy.

See also [this definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/food), with examples, from Oxford Dictionaries.

Comment: By the way, is it foods is in such case or foods are?

Comment: @SovereignSun: "Foods are," as it's a plurality of varieties/types/kinds of food – *Gluten-free foods are fruit, vegetables, potatoes, and fish, among others.*